# Google Maps V3 api only displays some of the markers from a Javascript Loop

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I've been searching all the responses from Google Map Api questions regarding this and Have not been able to come up with a resolution.

I have a javascript array "js_pickup_location_info" 17 objects in it including all the lat long info.  I'm trying to iterate through and show all 17 markers on google maps. However, only 8 of the 17 markers show up on the map. Below is the code.

Thanks for any help.

```
function initialize() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(myLat,myLong);
    var mapOptions = {
         zoom: 14,
         center: myLatlng,
         mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
     }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
    var c= js_pickup_location_info.length;
    console.log(c);
    for (var i=0; i<c; i++){

        pickup_id= js_pickup_location_info[i]['pickup_id'];
        pickup_latlng= new google.maps.LatLng(js_pickup_location_info[i]['latitude'],js_pickup_location_info[i]['longitude']);
        contentString= '<div id="content">'+
                '<div id="siteNotice">'+
                '</div>'+
                '<h2 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">'+js_pickup_location_info[i]['address']+'</h2>'+
                '<div id="bodyContent">'+
                '<p>'+js_pickup_location_info[i]['pickup_day']+'</p>'+
                '<p>HOLDER Insert Ajax Link</p>'+
                '</div>'+
                '</div>';

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: contentString
                // could add size: new google.maps.Size(50,50)
            });
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: pickup_latlng,
                map: map,
                title: pickup_id
            });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
              infowindow.open(map,marker);
            });
            }
        }


function loadScript() {
  var script = document.createElement("script");
  script.type = "text/javascript";
  script.src = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCH-RktY6ZGD8AlwxEzzF28nzCrRMjEfjE&sensor=false&callback=initialize";
  document.body.appendChild(script);
}

window.onload = loadScript;
```

Comment: have you made sure that the coordinates are not the same for some markers? you might have created 17 markers but if some of them have the same lat,lng then they will stack on top

Comment: yep, all the coordinates are unique.

Answer (score 0):

Variable scoping problem, make changes to following part as given bellow and it should work

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.setContent(this.html);
    infowindow.open(map, this);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I tried the changes but I'm still having the same issue.

Comment: Did you try deleting your internet temp files and ctrl - f5 for the page you are working on?  Sorry have to ask as this has killed me many times in my web apps.

Comment: @user1634246, here is a search result of [Google Map](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+google+maps+api3), this may help you.

Comment: Smith, yes I cleared the Temp files but no luck, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Sheikh Heera, thanks for the link I'll look through to see if I can find anything useful